# CarrierWave RMagick - How do I cause manipulate! to be called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, image-resizing, minimagick

Greetings wise people,

I am trying to use MiniMagick with CarrierWave in Rails 3 to resize and store an image according to the instructions here:  http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/MiniMagick.html

I can upload images with no processing.  The image is uploaded and I can see it in the directory and the application.  But when I try to perform processing on the image, the block inside `manipulate!` method is never being called.  Do you know how I can solve this?

I have the following uploader that works:

```
class MyContentImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
end
```

With this code, I am able to upload images using my form and view them on the result page.  Everything is peachy.

I added a simple resize to the uploader like this:

```
class MyContentImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_fit: [200,200]
end
```

After adding the process call, the image does not upload, but I also never see an error.  I tried to add a custom method to the uploader and saw the same result:

```
class MyContentImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  def do_stuff:
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.resize_to_fit(200,200)
    end
  end
end
```

Nothing happens.  The image doesn't update on the server, but I never see an error.  I placed some `raise` calls into the `do_stuff` method to see how far the call was executing.  It turns out the `do_stuff` method is being called, but the block inside `manipulate!` is not.  How could this be happening?  How would you troubleshoot this problem?

Additional info:
I have inside config/initializers/carrierwave.rb the following code, so I believe processing is enabled:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = true
end
```

I am using:

- Rails 3.2.12
- CarrierWave 0.8.0
- MiniMagick 3.5.0

Comment: Well for **do_stuff** you have to supply to add to existing process something like this **process :do_stuff**