# Having trouble getting multiple carrierwave processes to run

Tags: carrierwave, minimagick

I am attempting to optimize images when resizing them with Carrierwave but haven't had any luck getting this to work. Carrierwave is generating the different sized versions, but my custom optimize and the convert processes aren't running. I've tried calling the different processes in different places, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Could it be the same issue here: [CarrierWave RMagick - How do I cause manipulate! to be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503652/carrierwave-rmagick-how-do-i-cause-manipulate-to-be-called)

```
class FooUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Attempt #1
  process :convert => 'jpg'
  process :optimize
  version :meow do
    process :resize_to_fill => [700, 400]
  end


  # Attempt #2
  version :meow do
     process :convert => 'jpg', :optimize => nil, :resize_to_fill => [700, 400]
  end

  # Attempt #3
  version :meow do
    process :resize_to_limit => [700, 400]
    process :optimize
    process :convert => 'jpg'
  end

  # Attempt #4
  # Tried switching order around since they are being resized but not converted
  version :meow do
    process :convert => 'jpg'
    process :optimize
    process :resize_to_limit => [700, 400]
  end

  # Optimize method used by all versions
  def optimize
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.strip
      img.combine_options do |c|
        c.quality "96"
        c.depth "24"
        c.interlace "plane"
        #c.interlace "Plane" # Tried both cases, seen examples of both
      end
      img
     end
  end

end
```

Comment: you mean optimize the image that are resize

Comment: Yes, I would like the version to be converted to jpg, made interlaced and resized to the dimensions specified.

Comment: I get the error: `NameError (undefined local variable or method img` where do you define the `img`?

Comment: The block to manipulate gets a variable back. The sample above is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that not entirely possible they way you want if you are using carrierwave mini-magick or rmagick helper method

#### Solution 1)

if you get rid of carrierwave helper then perhaps it can work 
   do something like this

```
   process :custom_processing 

   def custom_processing 
     // You have to write you own code for and not CarrierWave helper method to achieve this 
     // write your own code to convert to jpg 
     // write your code to optimize
     // write your code to resize from the converted n optimize image
   end
```

this way you do all your processing in one shot ,having said but you have to dig in `mini_magick/rmagick` documentation to know how what method to call for each as you cant rely on carrierwave helper (since they are registered/called via `process` method and one cannot call call/invoke process inside process )

so something like this you can't achieve

```
  def custom_processing
    process :convert => 'jpg'
    process :optimize
    process :resize_to_fit  => [700, 400]
  end
```

#### Solution 2)

With  Carrierwave Helper but through multiple versions you can eventually achieve this

```
  version :jpg do
     process :convert => 'jpg'
  end 

  version :optimize_jpg ,:from => :jpg do 
    process :optimize
  end 

  version :meow,:from => :optimize_jpg do
    process :resize_to_limit => [700, 400]
  end
```

More reference of this can be found  [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Now this approach take care of headache of Approach 1 digging to documentation(since we are using Carrierwave helper methods), but as you can see you have to create multiple versions to achieve this

### Question : Why Multiple version ?

Well that how it Carrierwave work it create a uploader for each version and if `from` options isnt applied it consider the original images (uploaded images) as the source file(parent file)  create the desired version

Comment: That is interesting. The multiple processes I had setup were being called, the image itself just wasn't being altered. I've also seen mentions of this format around the internet which is where I picked it up.

I will need to give this a try since a single process should be quicker and use less resources than running multiple processes.

Comment: Well I still cannot get the convert working but otherwise rolling all of the actions into my own custom process appears to be working!